# Difference between browser().location().url() and browser().window().href() in Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Does anyone have ideas about the difference between browser().location().url() and browser().window().href() ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find much in the way of any API documentation on Jasmin, but the functions you mention seem to be part of AngularJS, to which the only documentation I could find that referenced either of those functions (with regards to Jasmin) was [this site](http://jonniespratley.me/testing-angularjs-with-jasmine/) which states the following:

```
browser().window().href() – Returns the window.location.href of the current loaded page.
browser().location().url() – Returns the $location.url() of the current page.
```

According to the W3C documentation, [`window.location.href`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) `returns the URL of the current page`, and according to the AngularJS documentation, [`$locatoin.url()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#url) `returns the url when called without any parameter`. Though neither of those is explicitly "clear", the examples they provide do give a little more clarity (especially that of `$location.url()`).

`windows.location.href` example from [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp):

```
Example: "Page location is " + window.location.href;
Result:  Page location is http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp
```

`$location.url()` example from [AJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#url):

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var url = $location.url();
// => "/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
```

Hope that helps.